# how to populate userform list from pivot table?

Tags: listboxitem

I need to populate a pivot table on a User form and have been successful with using just one field but I need 4 fields to show up.  here is what I have but keep getting errors:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim pvtTable As PivotTable
   Dim pvtDeliv, pvtDoc, pvtName, pvtMaterial As PivotField
   Dim lngIndex As Long
   Dim arrData() As String

 Set pvtTable = Worksheets("orders").PivotTables("orders")
   Set pvtDoc = pvtTable.PivotFields("OriginDoc.")
   Set pvtDeliv = pvtTable.PivotFields("Deliv.Date")
   Set pvtMaterial = pvtTable.PivotFields("Material")
   Set pvtName = pvtTable.PivotFields("Name")

    ListBox1.ColumnCount = 4

    For lngIndex = 1 To pvtDeliv.PivotItems.Count
    UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem pvtDeliv.PivotItems(lngIndex).Name.Value
    ListBox1.List(lngIndex, 2) = pvtMaterial.PivotItems(lngIndex).Name.Value
    ListBox1.List(lngIndex, 3) = pvtName.PivotItems(lngIndex).Name.Value
    ListBox1.List(lngIndex, 4) = pvtDoc.PivotItems(lngIndex).Name.Value

    Next


  End Sub
```

That's the pivot table I'm trying to populate

[Pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/In8J7.jpg)

thanks in advance.
Martyna

Comment: Adding a few more tags may help your question to get more attention. For example: what language is this? Visual Basic?

Answer (score 0):

After some investigating I figured it out and here is the revised code:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim pvtTable As PivotTable
   Dim pvtDeliv, pvtDoc, pvtName, pvtMaterial As PivotField
   Dim lngIndex As Long
   Dim arrData() As String

   Set pvtTable = Worksheets("orders").PivotTables("orders")
   Set pvtDoc = pvtTable.PivotFields("OriginDoc.")
   Set pvtDeliv = pvtTable.PivotFields("Deliv.Date")
   Set pvtMaterial = pvtTable.PivotFields("Material")
   Set pvtName = pvtTable.PivotFields("Name")

    ListBox1.ColumnCount = 4

    For lngIndex = 1 To pvtDeliv.PivotItems.Count
    UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem
    ListBox1.List(lngIndex - 1, 0) = pvtDeliv.PivotItems(lngIndex).Name
    ListBox1.List(lngIndex - 1, 1) = pvtMaterial.PivotItems(lngIndex).Name
    ListBox1.List(lngIndex - 1, 2) = pvtName.PivotItems(lngIndex).Name
    ListBox1.List(lngIndex - 1, 3) = pvtDoc.PivotItems(lngIndex).Name

    Next


  End Sub
```